# Pass parameter to external diff tool of gitk

Tags: gitk

I tried to set external diff tool for gitk via Edit->Preference->External diff tool, but I cannot specify any extra parameter to the tool, like `-d` is needed for vimdiff. I tried quote the executable name and parameter separately like `"vim.exe" "-d"` but does't work. How to specify such extra diff tool parameters in gitk?

Answer (score 0):

I created an [exe wrapper](https://github.com/ThomsonTan/ExeRedirector) to pass extra command line option to vim as `vim.exe -d`.